# What is the equation for a tangent to the graph of $y=\arcsin(x/2)$ at the origin?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I believe arc sin is the same as inverse sin but then I don't know how to deal with taking the derivative of that.

Comment: Have you looked in the Wikipedia?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_trigonometric_functions. The derivative of Arcsin is right there in a table. For x/2 you can apply the rule that f'(Cx) = Cf'(x).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
To take derivatives, take $\sin$ of both sides: $\sin y = x/2$ and now differentiate implicitly.

**EDIT**
In response, let me show how implicit differentiation would work. Differentiate both sides of
$$\sin y = x/2$$
with respect to $x$ to get
$$y'\cos y = 1/2.$$
Now use the original relationship between $x$ and $y$ to get
$$
y' = \frac{1}{2\cos y} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 y}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1 - (x/2)^2}}
   = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1 - x^2/4}}
   = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}
$$

Comment: I'm not sure how to differentiate implicitly

Comment: @Hannah see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula for the derivative of the inverse:

$$
\arcsin ' x = \frac 1{\cos(\arcsin x)} = \frac 1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$ and then take the composition with $x\to x/2$:

$$
\frac d{dx} \left(\arcsin  \frac x2 \right)=
 \frac 12 \frac 1{\sqrt{1-x^2/4}}
$$
Take $x=0$ and you get the equation of the tangent line:
$$
T(x) = \arcsin 0 + \left.\frac d{dx} \left(\arcsin  \frac x2 \right)
\right|_{x=0} x
=\frac x2
$$

[image]

Comment: I wonder why -1, look ok to me.

Comment: I wonder too. If the downvoter would care to comment...

Comment: I added the graph.